# Mysql multiple inner join don't work

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables A & B

```
A :
id
data

B :
key
value
A_id
```

I have a problem with my sql query (its hard to explain it, so i create an [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae2a2/1/0))

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B b1 ON b1.key = '20' AND b1.A_id = A.id
INNER JOIN B b2 ON b2.key = '18' AND b2.A_id = A.id
WHERE
    b1.value = '1900' AND 
    b2.value >= '1900'
```

in this example, I'm supposed to get (A.id = 12 & A.id = 13) but nothing

```
CREATE TABLE A
    (`id` int, `data` int)
;

INSERT INTO A
    (`id`, `data`)
VALUES
    (11, 11),
    (12, 11),
    (13, 12)
;

CREATE TABLE B
    (`key` int, `value` int, `A_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO B
    (`key`, `value`, `A_id`)
VALUES
    (20, 1900, 12),
    (2, 19, 11),
    (11, 19, 11),
    (9, 19, 11),
    (18, 1950, 13),
    (19, 1950, 12)
;
```

Any idea ?

thanks

Comment: Can you explain what kind of result you hope to get? Do you want rows where b.key is 20 while b.value is 1900, and rows where b.key is 18 while b.value >=20?

Comment: This is easily done with some `AND/OR` logic in the `WHERE` clause, but I suspect your real data and requirement might be more complex than this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae2a2/13

Comment: it's a bit more complex yes, but your answer helped me to consider the AND / OR, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you code for more than 10 minutes, you will learn to despise the phrase "don't work"... "don't work" is the phrase that doesn't work.

/rant

You are trying to join tables in an effort to filter.  Instead, filter accordingly.  Check this out:

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B b1 ON b1.A_id = A.id
WHERE
  (b1.key = '20' AND b1.value = '1900')
  OR
  (b1.key = '18' AND b1.value >= '1900')
```

That asks for what you want and joins only when necessary.

Comment: A minor thing, b2 shoudnt be there.

Comment: @Mihai Thanks. An error is an error, though.  Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

`INNER JOIN` means that it will only return a result if a result exists in both tables. Since you inner join the same table twice each time with unique ids you will never get a result with those three results (table A inner join B inner join b).

I'd suggest something different:

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B on A.id = B.A_id
WHERE
(B.id = '20' AND B.value = '1980') OR (B.id = '18' AND B.value >= '1990')
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is using the same A.id for both joins - so it means they must be the same on the rows returned. For `b2.key = 18`, `b2.A_id` is **13**, while `b1.key = 20` forces a `b1.A_id` of **12**. So you want to get a return where `b1.A_id = b2.A_id`, where one is 12 and the other is 13. If you change the query to

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B b1 ON b1.key = '20' AND b1.A_id = A.id
INNER JOIN B b2 ON b2.key = '19' AND b2.A_id = A.id
WHERE
    b1.value = '1900' AND 
    b2.value >= '1900'
```

you'll get a return of 12 for A.id.